# integrable function on $R^n$

Tags: integration, absolute-convergence

Consider the function : 
$$G(x,t)=(4\pi t)^{-\frac{n}{2}}e^{-\frac{\mid x\mid^2}{4t}}$$
where $x \in \Bbb R^n$, $t\geq 0$ and $\mid .\mid$ denote the euclidean norm on $\Bbb R^n$. In my course, it is written :

> $G_1(x)=G(x,1)$ is integrable because the integral converges absolutely.

I don't understand this at all. If we would like to show that $G_1$ is integrable on $\Bbb R^n$, what do we have to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_{\mathbb R^{n}} e^{-c|x|^{2}}dx= \prod _i\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-cx_i^{2}}dx_i=(\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-t^{2}}dt )^{n} <\infty$ for any $c >0$.

Comment: and this is enough to state that the function is integrable on $R^n$ ?

Comment: Yes, the integral exist and is finite as  a Riemann integral as well as  a Lebesgue integral. @Dicordi

Comment: I agree on the fact that it is finite, so, in $R^n$, if the integral is finite then the integral exists ?

Comment: For a continuous function, yes. The integral over any finite rectangle exists by continuity and you  can let the rectangle increase to the whole of $\mathbb R^{n}$ to show that the function is integrable. @Dicordi

Comment: so if a have any function $f : {R}^n \mapsto {R}$, in order to show that $\int_{{R}^n}f(x_1,...,x_n)dx_1...dx_n$ is Rieman integrable, if the function is continuous, I just have to show that the integral is finite ? Just to be sure

Comment: Yes, that is true. @Dicordi

Comment: okay thank you !